# Useful directory watcher service - why doesn't it work?

Tags: c#, windows-services

ServerFault suggested I ask here.  I need a directory watcher to trigger a command line FTP client to upload some files to a server.  I don't care for the idea of keeping a connection to the server all day, so I need a directory watcher.  This looks perfect, and I have tried everything I know possible.  But I have hit the limit of my knowledge for something that is obviously very simple.  If any one is interested, would point out my mistake?

I found this useful directory watcher service [through google](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/directorywatcherservice.aspx), but I have been unable to get it to work for me.  I try to avoid asking for help with low skill things like this, but I have exhausted my knowledge and I don't know any C# so I can't troubleshoot the code.  The log files say the service starts, and enters running mode, and stops, but nothing happens when I move a file into the watched folder.

If you find the code interesting or useful would you try it and let me know what works?

FWIW, this is the config file I was using: (but can't get it to appear)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <section name="watchInformation" type="DirectoryWatcher.WatchInformation, DirectoryWatcher"/>
   </configSections>
   <appSettings>     
         <add key="maxConcurrentProcesses" value="1"/>  
   </appSettings>
   <watchInformation>
      <directoriesToWatch>  
            <directoryToWatch path="C:\ftp_folder">
               <fileSetsToWatch>
                  <fileSetToWatch>
                     <eventsToWatch>
                        <eventToWatch type="All"/>
                     </eventsToWatch>
                     <programsToExecute>
                        <programToExecute path="cmd.exe" arguments="/C" />
                     </programsToExecute>
                  </fileSetToWatch>
               </fileSetsToWatch>     
            </directoryToWatch>
      </directoriesToWatch>
   </watchInformation>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you ask in the article's comments ?

Comment: @Ben : "the service starts, and enters running mode, and stops"  The service stops running?  That would explain why you're not seeing anything.  Is there an event logged in the event viewer?

Comment: HI,
    it seems u got the sourcecode for the app.. why dont u just attach the debugger and see what happens inside..

i dint see the source code of the app u have mentioned.. but am sure they must implement the .Net FileSystemWatcher class and raise the events if there is a any change in dir.. so u can easily figure out this by debugging..

Answer (score 0):

Your program might not be able to find `cmd.exe`.

Try to fully specify the path... usually its `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

Answer (score 0):

What ID is the program running under?  What groups is it a member of?  It might not have permissions to run cmd.exe - in the past, I've had to add security groups to cmd.exe on a server to allow a low-privilege account to run it.